# Scilab and Microsoft Teams

Tags: graphics, microsoft-teams, scilab

Can anyone help me with a tutorial on how to use Scilab within Microsoft Teams? I'm not able to run the programs, generate the graphics within Teams. Thanks a lot!

Comment: this is off topic in here...  however try to share desktop screen instead of individual window in some cases the graphics is shared that way and blank black in the other (especially DirectX/HLSL and OpenGL/GLSL based apps)

Comment: I've done this. The notepad screen I can share. The problem is the graphics that I need to show.

Comment: try to post this on superuser ... also try to find out what kind of rendering your SciLab uses (which lib, full screen, what rendering techniques)  that might hint something ...

Comment: Hi @Marcus Vinicius P. de Souza, Could you please elaborate the question and please share the documentation that you are referring.

Comment: Hi @Marcus Vinicius P. de Souza, are you still facing the issue?

Comment: Hello, @Jagadeesh-MSFT! Sorry, but I am till finding it difficult to use scilab along with teams. However, if I share the scinote by teams (via desktop), everything occurs normally. The problem is when I generate a graph, for example. This graph does not appear to the user. Similarly, when I want to draw up a block diagram using Xcos. Thank you so much for your attention. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

As a part of teams platform under the app capabilities you could build you app in teams
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/build-your-first-app/build-first-app-overview#app-capabilities-and-tools.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Jagadeesh-MSFT!!